# Special Characters within URL Variable

Tags: php

Currently I am trying to fiddle around with the [Deezer API](https://developers.deezer.com/api/explorer?url=track/3135556) and running into a slight issue, I am trying to gather content from this artist.

**XYLØ - Nothing Left To Say**

```
https://api.deezer.com/search/track?q=XYLØ - Nothing Left To Say
```

The page above displays the content in a JSON format, however when I use the following code.

```
$id = 'XYLØ - Nothing Left To Say';
$h = str_replace(' ', '+', $id);
$json_string = 'https://api.deezer.com/search/track?q='.$h;
$jsondata = file_get_contents($json_string);
$obj = json_decode($jsondata,true);
```

I get an empty pallet on my image request.

```
$obj['data'][0]['album']['cover_medium']
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work properly?

Comment: Do you even get the contents of the file?  `I get an empty pallet on my image request.` that doesn't tell us where the error happens.  Maybe your file is named wrong, maybe it doesn't exist.  How do we know.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I don't get the contents, because of the `Ø` in the request, `failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request ` sorry, should have specified that in my OP.

Comment: I was going to say, because it works fine [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab372171232f5386c55eec76205091f06b28ce87) when I manually put the JSON in, as you can't use file functions in the sandbox....  So the question is have you tried  [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)  as in `$json_string = 'https://api.deezer.com/search/track?q='.urlencode($h);` and you won't need the stuff to replace spaces with `+` as it does that.   `This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix that solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: I posted it as an answer, I wasn't sure it would work in this case, but that is typically what I use if I even question what the query argument is going to contain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP's built in function for query args,

```
 //changed $h to $id (see below)
$json_string = 'https://api.deezer.com/search/track?q='.urlencode($id);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

> This function is convenient when encoding a string to be used in a query part of a URL, as a convenient way to pass variables to the next page.

You can also do away with this stuff (AKA remove it):

```
  $h = str_replace(' ', '+', $id);
```

As urlencode does that to!!!.

**As a Bonus**

You can use

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

> http_build_query — Generates a URL-encoded query string from the associative (or indexed) array provided.

To build the whole query string from an array, which I figure may be useful to someone reading this...

Comment: str_replace() as you demonstrated is not equivalent of urlencode(). do not provide misleading answer

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski `str_replace() as you demonstrated is not equivalent of urlencode(). do not provide misleading answer` - I didn't demonstrate it, I said to Do away with it AKA remove it.  Unless your suggesting that this `echo urlencode("some string");` will not add a `+` in there, which it certainly will.  I am well aware that `str_replace` is not a substitute for `urlencode` Hence this answer, which is the exact opposite of that..  Cheers!

Comment: PS - I added `(AKA remove it)` and changed `As it does that to!!!.` to `As urlencode does that to!!!.` just to be crystal clear.  But the rest of the answer was not changed...  Just to be clear, I do appreciate the feedback and updated the question to be more readable.

Comment: In this particular case *only*. Bringing str_replace() is completely wrong in the context of url encoding and mislead uneperienced people they can use it. Same nonsense as bringing addslashes() in context od sql queries.